# AirPrint and Bonjour

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4, bonjour, airprint

Do I have to use an Apple AirPrint capable printer to use AirPrint in my iPad app?

Can't I just set up a shared Bonjour print service on a Mac and connect to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use AirPrint printers. You may have luck with [Printopia](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/printopia/), but I’ve not tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Setup an airprint service on a ubuntu box in your network that has any printer attached to it. See here:

http://hartlessbydesign.com/blog/view/197-airprint-with-ubuntu-1010

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can share Mac-printers and access them from your iOS devices.

Under OS X 10.10 you need to republish a modified Bonjour announcement. Add `,_universal` as service sub-type and `image/urf` to the pdl values:

Example

```
dns-sd                   \
 -R "AirPrinter"         \
 _ipp._tcp,_universal    \
 .                       \
 631                     \
    rp=printers/ColorJet \
    pdl=application/pdf,image/urf \
    URF=none
```

There's a description in German available in [c't 21/2015](https://shop.heise.de/katalog/drucken-uber-bande).